# Knockout viewmodel update from another viewmodel click event

Tags: knockout.js, click, viewmodel, bind

I have two tables with ko data binding to two models. I am able to bind the data with the two models.

My Goal:

When a row in Model#1 (in this case patientmodel) is clicked, the Model#2 should be updated with the corresponding data.

**Problem:** Not able to trigger a Click event for Model #1.

```
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: Patients">
            <tr data-bind="click: $root.echoMe">
                <td class="id"><a href="#" data-bind="text: patID"></a>

                </td>
                <td data-bind="text: patName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: patBirthDate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: patSex"></td>
             </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Where the echoMe is defined in the patientModel as:

```
self.echoMe = function () {
    console.log("able to trigger click !");
};
```

jsfiddle gives me the error:

> Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return
>   $root.echoMe }"

This breaks even while populating the view itself with the data. The first is displayed and then the error comes up.

I looked out knockout documentation and other examples on jfiddle, but I am not able to figure out yet since last night as to why this is not working for mr.

Jsfiddle code:

**http://jsfiddle.net/j9HJm/7/**

Insight and help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are calling `ko.applyBindings()` more than once, you probably aren't structuring your view model correctly.

Comment: Yes, I think that I should do update model instead of re-binding it. But what I found just now is: this same code in jsfiddle works perfectly when I run it through interactive learning tutorials on knockout: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/. My click events are fired and model is updated

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle code to refresh the viewmodel than rebinding. But still click events are not firing unlike the smooth working of code in knockoutjs.com interactive tuts.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, I unchecked firebug lite and jquery lint in the "Frameworks and Extensions" section on the sidebar. That took care of your jsfiddle breaking.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `jQuery (edge)` version in JSfiddle.
`jQuery (edge)` is a last build of jquery lib and it is not stable.
Use stable version instead. E.g. *2.0.2*.
With stable jquery version, your example works as expected:

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SWPct/)

Comment: Thanks llya for the jsfiddl demo. It is working fine.